# Downloading Dependencies with Composer in Vagrant Virtual Machine causes Broken Folders

Tags: ubuntu, paypal, permissions, vagrant, composer-php

I have an Ubuntu 12.04.5 virtual machine running as a Vagrant Box.

I want to now install some Composer Dependencies. Here is my `composer.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "sample/website",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php" : "*"
    }
}
```

Everything works out fine, but now when I navigate to:

```
/vagrant/site/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib
```

and run `ls -la` I am presented with this:

```
ls: cannot access PayPal: No such file or directory
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 102 Oct 23 19:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 510 Oct 23 19:16 ../
?????????? ? ?       ?         ?            ? PayPal
```

I cannot `cd`, `rm` or `chmod` or `chown` the directory. Some places suggest trying to change its permissions because I may not have permissions to exectue the file, but I cannot perform any operation.

I can access this completely fine from my host machine (OSX 10.9.5).

This even happened when I cloned the PayPal repo directly from GitHub.

Any clues?

Comment: what happens when you run "sudo ls -l PayPal"?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be part of a wider problem whereby Vagrant loses track of synced folders. The problem is also detailed here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/985

The solution which I grabbed from that link was to follow this: http://blog.csanchez.org/2012/05/03/automatically-download-and-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-vagrant/

You need to install the latest version of guest additions:

```
vagrant gem install vagrant-vbguest
```

Then in your `Vagrantfile`, add

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|   
    # set auto_update to false, if do NOT want to check the correct additions   
    # version when booting this machine   
    config.vbguest.auto_update = false
end
```